# HTML5 video - measuring playback

Tags: html, video

Is it possible to measure viewing time for the 'video' tag? I see that it has 'onplaying' and 'onpause' events so I could probably fake a timer.

Just wondering if there is something more that Im missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML5 media elements fire a 'timeupdate' event. See http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/media-elements.html#event-mediacontroller-timeupdate. When that event fires, you can check .currentTime for the current time and .duration for the length of the video. It also fires a 'durationchange' event.

Full HTML5 Media DOM Interface Specs: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/media-elements.html

Answer (score 0):

```
videoElement.currentTime
```

[Try it on jsFiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/adamzr/9cR4T/)

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLMediaElement

Comment: This would be the current time for the playback head. Im thinking more about elapsed viewing time.

Comment: @ethrbunny What is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to accomplish the same thing in a project I'm working on.
I did it using a [jquery stopwatch plugin](http://www.seph.dk/blog/projects/javascript-stopwatch-class/).

This is the JS you'll need:

```
var w = new Stopwatch();

document.querySelector("#video").addEventListener("playing", Start, false);
document.querySelector("#video").addEventListener("pause", Stop, false);
document.querySelector("#video").addEventListener("waiting", Stop, false);

function Start() {
    if ($("#video").get(0).paused == true)
        Stop();
    else
        w.start();
}

function Stop() {
    w.stop();
}
```

And this is how you get the elapsed view time (in milliseconds):

```
var e = w.getElapsed();
time = (((e.hours * 3600) + (e.minutes * 60) + e.seconds) * 1000 + e.milliseconds); // Total view time
```

Keep in mind - this is not the most accurate way to do this, yet it is the best I've managed to accomplish with my coding skills.

Good luck!